# init jagged array to zeros

Tags: c#, arrays, init, jagged-arrays

Is there a less verbose way to init this jagged array ?

```
    var r = new int[a.Length][];
    for (int i=0; i<a.Length; i++)
    {
        r[i] = new int[2];
    }
```

I don't want a multidimensional array `int[,]` because I may later need to assign to some elements other than `int[2]`

Comment: Mandatory link: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: I meant faster to type not faster cpu

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, you cant implicitly `default` a jagged array on initialisation.

Jagged arrays are actually just an array of something (int this case another array) and as such each element has to be initialised by its self.

May i suggest using

- A *Multidimensional Array* instead, this will in turn be `defaulted` on initialisation.
- Failing that you can write a generic helper to `default` and initialise
- Or an *Extension Method*

Comment: for my case a multidimensional array could be quite sparse, for example i might have `a[0]=int[2] ....... a[1000]=int[100]` which would imply `int[1000,100]` which i assume allocates far more memory than `int[1000][]`

Answer (score 1):

The Linq equivalent is only *slightly* less verbose:

```
int[][] r = Enumerable.Range(1,a.Length)
                      .Select(i => new int[2])
                      .ToArray();
```